# how to categorize in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

just think I have a table like shown below

```
**id**                           **product**

2                                 chocolate
1                                 chocolate    
2                                 pepsi
3                                 fanta
2                                 pepsi
4                                 chocolate
5                                 chips
3                                 pizza
1                                 coke
2                                 chips
6                                 burger
7                                 sprite
0                                 pepsi
```

and want to arrange the above table in the manner shown below using only mysql

```
**id**                   **product**
0                          pepsi
1                          chocolate, coke
2                          chocolate,fanta,chips      
3                          fanta,pizza
4                          chocolate
5                          chips
6                          burger
7                          sprite
```

how do I do it?

Comment: Please format your code or explain in more detail - this is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, group_concat(distinct product) as products
from your_table
group by id
order by id
```

Comment: What is not getting ordered. Please be more specific